# WhirlyGlobe-Maply Poles

Tags: ios, iphone, import, frameworks

i'm trying to use the binary library from WhirlyGlobe-Maply in one of my new projects. The library can be found here: http://mousebird.github.io/WhirlyGlobe/ WhirlyGlobe-Maply poles look always flatten and not even, round like a globe even when I set `layer.coverPoles = true;`

it looks like this:

[image: flat poles image]

how can i make it look like the rest of the globe shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data sets most commonly provided (or made) online are in a coordinate system that does not cover the poles (spherical mercator, actually web mercator).  That's just how spherical mercator works.

To fix it, you need to provide a data set in a coordinate system that does cover the poles, such as plate carrée.  That's just unwrapped latitude/longitude.

Unless you're doing something fairly big and serious, I can tell you that it's not going to be worth the trouble.  Just stick with the web mercator data sets.

Also, in future, I recommend opening an [issue on github](https://github.com/mousebird/WhirlyGlobe/issues) for this sort of thing.   I don't monitor stackoverflow that closely.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and attempt to help me with this problem. I am a great admirer of your work, and would like to take this opportunity to thank you enduring once such a great masterpiece that you have created. I am going to take advantage of "issue on github" next time so that others can learn from your expertice when you clearly know better than us since you made it all to start with.

Comment: It will be great if there was an opportunity to decide the color of the poles. I am not in any way as expert in the field as you. It will be a great helping hand if you could show me how I can color the poles with vector or placing pictures on them to cover the flat. Thank you for everything and god bless you

Comment: Thanks!  For each triangle it makes in the tessellation at the ends of the globe, it picks a color from the texels right at the edge.  Sometimes that works well, other times not.  Setting the color directly wouldn't be too hard, but you'd have to dig way down into LoadedTile.mm (I think).  This would be a good thing to open an issue for.  Maybe I can get it into 2.4.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and again! although I still have no idea how I personally can solve the problem since I'm not so good or near that great knowledge you possess, but you have made things more clear for me. :)  and i'm going to open an issue right now